# DTMC with a stationary distribution is positive recurrent

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, stationary-processes

I have an irreducable discrete time Markov chain (DTMC) $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ with finite state space $\mathcal{X}$. The DTMC has a stationary distribution $\pi$, such that $\pi = \pi P$, where $P$ is the transition probability matrix of the Markov chain. I need to prove that the Markov chain is positive recurrent.

I have that, if the Markov chain is a closed, finite, communicating class then it is positive recurrent. How does having an invariant distribution imply positive recurrence (or that the Markov chain is a finite, closed communicating class)? Thanks.

Comment: You need more assumptions - either that $\{X_n\}$ is on a finite state space or is irreducible. The existence of a stationary distribution does not imply positive recurrence.

Comment: @Math1000 I've made edits to reflect what you said, thanks